# Заполнение БД перед каждым тестом Junit 5

Tags: java, spring, junit

Перед классом теста имеется аннотация `@SpringJUnitConfig(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring-app.xml",})` , благодаря которой заполняется БД перед запуском теста. Но при выполнении всех тестов класса одновременно заполнение происходит только один раз, что приводит к ошибкам. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: попробуйте добавить `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

Comment: Спасибо, решило проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оформлю как ответ, чтобы было проще найти в будущем.

Необходимо добавить аннотацию на тестовый класс.

```
 @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```